# How to remove effects of a CSS class inside @media?

Tags: html, css

I have a situation like

```
<div class="foo">...</div>
```

where

```
.foo {float:left;}
```

How can I "disable" that `float` effect when I am inside `@media`?

Comment: I'm not sure whether your questio is a general one, about any CSS setting, or specifically about float. In the case of float you can set float: none inside the media query if that's what's required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can unset any property as in `CSS`

```
@media not|only mediatype and (expressions) {
   .foo {
       float: unset;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `float: initial` for that. This makes that element to default value. [For More Info](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_initial.asp)